# Python Dash: How to style dash components with custom CSS?

Tags: python, html, css, web-applications, plotly-dash

I'm having trouble styling the upload component from Dash using a custom css file. I know that the dcc has a style argument, but I would rather have my styling in the CSS file. I can't figure out why it won't style properly; could somebody please point out what I'm doing incorrectly?

main.py

```
html.Div(
            className='upload-data',
            children=[
                dcc.Upload(
                    className='upload-data--uploader',
                    id='upload-data',
                    children=html.Div([
                        'Drag and Drop or ',
                        html.A('Select CSV File')
                    ], className='upload-data--text')
                )]
        ),
```

stylesheet.css

```
.upload-data .upload-data--uploader .upload-data--text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  lineHeight: 60px;
  borderWidth: 1px;
  borderStyle: dashed;
  borderRadius: 5px;
  textAlign: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I know very litle about CSS and Dash specifically, but have you tried to remove this `double-dashed` class name?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*

Comment: No but I have other classes with double dash and they seem to be affected by the CSS styling

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue before, and finally, I could solve the problem.

I think the css file description should be like this. The "textAlign" should be "text-align".

```
.upload-data .upload-data--uploader .upload-data--text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
```